# Show only dna alignment score in biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, dna-sequence, pairwise

I have DNA sequence data.
For instance,

```
X="ACGGGT"
Y="ACGGT"
```

I want to know the alignment score, thus I used biopython pairwise2 function.
For example,

```
from Bio import pairwise2
from Bio.pairwise2 import format_alignment

alignments = pairwise2.align.globalxx(X, Y)
for a in alignments:
    print(format_alignment(*a))
```

This successfully showed the DNA alignment but I only need the score as below.
Is there any way to show score only?

[image]

I used biopython but if there is a better way, that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the 3rd item of each alignment tuple (or for the best score only parse the `score_only` argument):

```
>>> from Bio import pairwise2
>>> X="ACGGGT"
>>> Y="ACGGT"
>>> alignments = pairwise2.align.globalxx(X, Y)
>>> [a[2] for a in alignments]
[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
>>> pairwise2.align.globalxx(X, Y, score_only=True)
5.0
```

Also see the newer `Bio.Align` module, which may be more performant for many use cases. If you want just the best score, you can you use `aligner.score()` as [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6056900/markus) comments:

```
>>> from Bio import Align
>>> aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
>>> alignments = aligner.align(X,Y)
>>> [a.score for a in alignments]
[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
>>> aligner.score(X, Y)
5.0
```

If you *only* want the scores, then avoiding generating the full alignments is the fastest and most memory efficient way for both modules.

Comment: For ```PairwiseAligner``` instead of doing ```aligner.align(X, Y)``` you can just do ```aligner.score(X, Y)```. Note that calculating only the scores (in ```pairwise2```with ```score_only=True```, in ```PairwiseAligner``` with ```score```) is faster and saves memory. So you should always do this when you are not interested in the alignment itself.

Comment: First thank you very much. I tested the two methods on 2 genes with first=20803 and second=30386. The**pairwise2**  with **score_only=True**  gives around 11 sec, but  **aligner.score** gives around 3sec,  which is almost 4x faster.